# How to breed with a female starter in Pokemon X?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I started with a female Froakie in Pokemon X, but I did not know you had to have a male to breed. I finished the game but I want to breed my Greninja. How can I do that?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can breed almost any Pokemon with [Dittos](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ditto_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) regardless of gender. Ditto can be caught in the [Pokemon Village](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Village) or in certain Normal-type [Friend Safaris](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Friend_Safari).

Alternatively, as your Greninja is female, you can breed it with a male of a different type of Pokemon, so long as the male is in the same egg group as the Froakie evolutionary line.

Froakie and its evolutions are in the [Water 1](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Water_1_(Egg_Group)) egg group, which contains 108 Pokemon. For example, Poliwag, Psyduck and Marrill are all in Water 1 and relatively accessible to catch in-game.

Comment: Realistically though, there's rarely a reason to use anything but a Ditto. If you don't care about competitive play, there is zero reason not to use a Ditto.

Comment: @ApologizeandreinstateMonica The reason to not use a ditto would be that you don't have a ditto, but you have some other Pokémon from the egg group that works. Or if you're trying to pass on egg moves / nature's

Comment: Yeah that's why I added it. OP likely already has other Pokemon in Water 1, they may not have a ditto